# Drag an imageview to a specific area to remove it

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I was just wondering if anyone had any idea how I could remove an imageview that has been dragged to a specific area. For example if you can dynamically add imageviews such as novelty glasses to a face, is there an easy way to remove the glasses if they're dragged over a bin icon for example?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit tricky if you're not very experienced with Android development, but not impossible. While moving the `ImageView` around, you could use [Rect.intersects(Rect a, Rect b)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect)) to test if the area of the ImageView intersects the area of bin in any way.

If this is true, you could change the colour of the bin and animate the translation and scale the ImageView to the centre of the bin upon release of the image.

Removing the view itself is simple in some kind of `ViewGroup` (e.g. `FrameLayout`), you simply call `container.removeView(imageView)`.